# Comparing datetime saved in database to now

Tags: php, mysql

I need to compare a date in my database to the current time, and if the date is older than the current time, it will change some stuff in the database.

$exp_date is the date I'm trying to compare to the current time and is datatype `datetime`

This is what I have so far, even though I was pretty confident it wouldn't work:

```
if( NOW() >= $exp_date ) {
    $query = "UPDATE orders SET active = '0' WHERE server_id = '$id'";
    $result = $connect->query( $query );
}
```

Also, $exp_date is currently not converted using strtotime. Not sure if I need to do that or not.

Comment: I would use a proper DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column and let MySQL do all the work, if possible.

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean exactly. Any idea what that would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid having to mess with conversion between MySQL date and Unix Timestamps, etc., you need to be storing your date in MySQL as a real `datetime` and you will compare it in the SQL where clause to the keyword `current_timestamp`:

```
$query = "UPDATE orders SET active = '0' WHERE server_id = '$id' AND date_time_field < current_timestamp";
$result = $connect->query( $query );
```

Comment: Is current_timestamp a default SQL command/field or something? Also, I'm not sure what a "real" datetime is, can't find much on google about it. I currently have my exp_date stored as a datetime, not sure if that's any different from a "real" datetime.

Comment: @Caden Grant, By real datetime I mean your field is defined as datatype `datetime` not `varchar` with something like "8/21/2014 6:44 PM" in it. And yes, `current_timestamp` is a keyword in MySQL that will give you the current datetime.